# Query items that are not in the list, without having a unique id in one column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm looking to create a Python script that displays the items that are no longer available in the store (location 1) but are available in the warehouse (location 99). E.g. a list with items needed to be restocked. The difficulty is, that instead of putting the item count on 0 for the store, the inventory management system just removes the item completely from the database. Plus the fact that items don't have a unique ID, but are a combination of two columns being serial number and the column with the item's size.

The (PostgreSQL) database is `restock` with one table `inventory` looking like this:

```
====================================================================
| serialnumber  | size     | location     | itemcount   | season   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1120.10.0369  | 140      | 99           | 8           | 74       |
| 1120.10.0369  | 140      | 1            | 2           | 74       |
| 1120.10.4011  | 170/176  | 99           | 3           | 74       |
| 1120.10.4011  | 170/176  | 1            | 2           | 74       |
| 1120.10.4011  | 86/92    | 99           | 1           | 74       |
| 1120.10.8006  | 158      | 99           | 1           | 74       |
| 1120.10.8006  | 158      | 1            | 2           | 74       |
```

In the above example, the item with serial number `1120.10.4011` and size `86/92` is available in location `99` (the warehouse) but there is no row with serial number `1120.10.4011` and size `86/92` where location is `1`, so that item I want to have on a list to be restocked.

I'm trying to show the items that don't exist in the data do this by using a count on a `GROUP BY` query:

```
getresult = "SELECT serialnumber, size, location, itemcount, season, COUNT(*)" + \
            "FROM inventory " + \
            "WHERE season = 74" + \
            "AND location != 1" + \
            "GROUP BY serialnumber, size " + \
            "HAVING COUNT(*) < 1"
```

However, this doesn't work as expected.

The question still stands:

- How can I retrieve a list with rows missing from the database?

Or

- How can I retrieve a list with rows where the serialnumber + size are there for location 99 but are not present with a location of 1?

Comment: Have you tried a LEFT JOIN with itself yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a subselect in a not exist clause:

```
getresult = """SELECT serialnumber, size FROM inventory i99
    WHERE season = 74 AND location = 99
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT serialnumber FROM inventory i1
        WHERE i1.serialnumber = i99.serialnumber
        AND i1.size = i99.size
        AND i1.location = 1)"""
```

That is the only way I know to find non existent values directly at the SQL level, because `IS NULL` even in an outer join test the value is the original table and not what will be returned by the select.

Comment: Indeed, the NOT EXIST in a subselect did the trick. Thank you Serge!

Answer (score 0):

```
getresult = """
select i99.serialnumber, i99.size, i99.itemcount, i99.season
from 
    inventory i99
    left join
    inventory i1 on
        (i99.serialnumber, i99.size, i99.season, i1.season, i99.location, i1.location) =
        (i1.serianumber, i1.size, 74, 74, 99, 1)
where i1.size is null
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Trying the above, it results in displaying ALL rows in the database. It doesn't seem to filter on season, nor on location. I will read up on LEFT JOIN, but any other pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You would get the correct results if you remove the `where i1.size is null`, and test for None values at Python level. But as the `where` clause is used on values from the original table, and as no row contains a null size, this query will return no row at all.